# Opening files in the browser with Java Web App

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a standalone simple java web application with servlets and jsp, say the name is FileDisplay I am access its home page through url - `http://localhost:8080/FileDisplay/index.jsp`.

What the application essentially does is, retrieves a list of file names(.xml's and .pdf's) with complete path. These files are stored in various external directories, say D:\ABCD, D:\XYZ, D:\PP\2012\08 etc but on the same machine as the web application just on a different drive. So the return list is something like-

```
D:\ABCD\filename1.xml  
D:\ABCD\filename2.xml  
D:\ABCD\pdf1.pdf
```

If I use a simple `<a href="">` in the jsp then it doesnt work. in the viewsource it looks like -

```
<a href="D:\ABCD\pdf1.pdf">file1</a>
```

I think it is beacause these files are not part of the webapp, so the container doesnt think it is local and hence unable to open them. When I place the mouse pointer over the link, the status bar shows as `file:///D:\ABCD\pdf1.pdf`. I also tried prefixing `file:///` in the `href`, even then it doesnt work. So I tried a few other things.
One thing I tried is setting the `Context` in Tomcat's `server.xml` but even that doesn't seem to work. I am using eclipse to build and deploy and run the tomcat, so the `server.xml` I modified for this context is one within the eclipse workspace.
The setting I used is -

```
<Context docBase="D:/ABCD" path="/File-Display/NB" reloadable="true"/>
```

I have another context set for the main application which is -

```
<Context docBase="FileDisplay" path="/FileDisplay" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:FileDisplay"/>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Does it explain a bit more now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the wrong way.

If you want to provide access to different files distributed in your file system create controller (servlet) that accepts URL, reads appropriate file and writes it to the response output stream.

This way you can control access to your resources, make them secure, etc. You will be able to modify your application easily (e.g. if you change the files location). Etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I had that in my mind to use stream but I dont really want to go too much with stream. But if there is no other option then may be use stream.